# how to make the label in pie figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df = data.frame("brand" = c("Samsung","Huawei","Apple","Xiaomi","OPPO","Other"),
            "share" = c(2090,1580,1210,930,860,3320))
```

Then I am trying to make a chart and put these numbers on them

```
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=share, fill=brand))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)+ 
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+ 
  geom_text(aes(y = share, label = brand), color = "white")
```

I simply want each number from share to be appeared on the part of that label but I cannot figure this out

Comment: [be cautious with pie charts](https://blog.datawrapper.de/pie-charts/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
> ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=share, fill=brand))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)+ 
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(share)),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This one works.

```
library("dplyr")
df <- df %>% arrange(desc(brand)) %>% mutate(lab.ypos = cumsum(share) - 0.5*share)

ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = share, fill = brand)) +
geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") + coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = share), color = "white")
```

[image: An example]

Comment: how can I change the X label title then?

Comment: Add this at the end: + xlab("Blah")